# How to handle exception throw in Flux.fromStream

Tags: java, reactive, flux

```
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Data>> getData(@RequestParam List<String> tagIds){
   
   Flux<S3Object> s3ObjectFlux = Flux.fromStream(tagIds.stream())
           .parallel()
           .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
           .flatMap(id -> fetchResources(id)) //S3Exception is thrown here 
           .flatMap(idS3Object -> Mono.just(s3Object))
           .doOnError((throwable) -> log.error(throwable))
           .ordered((u1, u2) -> u2.hashCode() - u1.hashCode());

   Mono<Data> data = s3ObjectFlux.collectList()
           .map(s3Objects -> new Data(s3Objects));  
}
```

I am iterating through tagIds and fetching the s3 objects here, if the object is not there or any exception is thrown, I want to log and ignore it and continue with next. But in this case if the S3Exception is thrown from fetchResource method while iterating, error is thrown to user as 500 instead I want empty list.

I dont see other options like onErrorMap or onErrorReturn

Comment: I see that `.flatMap(idS3Object -> Mono.just(s3Object))` is not necessary and also the error gets handled properly if its omitted. May I know why you need that step?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use something like [`onErrorContinue`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

Also, this `.ordered((u1, u2) -> u2.hashCode() - u1.hashCode())` does not really makes sense, you can have something like `sequential` instead to merge "rails".

Besides, I don't really understand this: `.flatMap(idS3Object -> Mono.just(s3Object))`. First of all, as it is, it does not compile, probably you have a typo there and you wanted something `flatMap(idS3Object -> Mono.just(s3Object))`. In this form, creating a `Mono` from an object and doing a `flatMap` on it is entirely pointless.

Putting this all together, I assume you wanted something like this:

```
Flux<S3Object> s3ObjectFlux = Flux.fromStream(tagIds.stream())
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .flatMap(this::fetchResources)
        .sequential()
        .onErrorContinue((error, object) -> {
            log.error(error);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ervin Szilagyi but I dont want to just log the error (which I can do with doOnError, I want to throw different error or just return mono.empty